# Problems with Page Lifecycle in my aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, page-lifecycle, prerender

What I am trying to do is to generate Linkbuttons whenever a user click on the static LinkButtons that are inside my aspx looks like this:

They look like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSubWeb" runat="server" OnCommand="lbWeb_Click" />
```

The method that fires is following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the Click event of the lbWeb control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="CommandEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
protected void lbWeb_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var url = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    using (var site = new SPSite(url))
    {
        using (var selectedWeb = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            ViewState["RelativeUrl"] = selectedWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
            ViewState["WebUrl"] = selectedWeb.Url;
            LoadWebItems(selectedWeb);
        }
    }
}
```

From what I know the page cycle works like this Page load -> Button click -> Page prerender.

So basicly when the user click on this linkbutton I want generate 5 linkbuttons dynamicly and also add and give them the `lbWeb_Click` event, but it aint getting fired. Nothing happens when I click on the generated LinkButtons.

So when I have stored the data to ViewState I use following method to generate these linkbuttons:

```
private void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RelativeUrl = (string)ViewState["RelativeUrl"];
    WebUrl = (string)ViewState["WebUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RelativeUrl))
    {
        LoadBreadCrumb(RelativeUrl, WebUrl);
    }
}
```

The `LoadBreadCrumb()` method looks like this:

```
private void LoadBreadCrumb(string relativeurl, string weburl)
{

    var relativePath = relativeurl.Substring(1);
    var urlList = weburl.ParseUrl();
    var linkList = new List<string>(relativePath.Split('/'));
    for (int i = 0; i < linkList.Count; i++)
    {
        var link = UppercaseFirst(linkList[i]);
        var linkButton = new LinkButton
        {
            Text = link + " > ",
            CssClass = "breadcrumb",
            CommandArgument = urlList[i]
        };
        linkButton.Command += lbWeb_Click;
        bcHolder.Controls.Add(linkButton);

    }

}
```

So basicly this codes generates the linkbuttons exacly as the way I want but the `lbWeb_Click` is not getting fired on those.

In other hand I have tried to put this code in Page_Load and that doesnt work well, its always one step behind. The LinkButtons aint getting displayed after a click event, but its generated after a Page_Load and then the click event on them actually works.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried breakpoints to see is anything is getting hit or it just seems that nothing is occuring?

Comment: Yep, the lbWeb_click is not getting fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating `LinkButton` instances *after* the page life-cycle passes the point where events are being processed. Hence at the time your event handler should have been called, there in fact *no* `LinkButton` instances in the `Page` and thus cannot be invoked.

You should create all dynamic controls (i.e. invoke `LoadBreadCrumb`) within the context of the `PreInit` event. See the ASP.NET page life-cycle [documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

---

Side note: They way you build the breadcrumb is a bit suboptimal in respect to URL path construction options in SharePoint. You should take into account that there are managed paths which do not correspond to any site collection (`SPSite`) directly, and that there are subsites (`SPWeb` nested within a `SPSite`'s root web site) along the path. Currently, by calling `new SPSite(url)` with an argument that is either a managed path or a subsite URL, you will end up with the immediatelly enclosing site collection which in turn denotes a different URL than what's in `url`.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? Is it possible maby to make sure lbWeb_Click gets fired before page_load? Yeah I am aware of that and for this solution it works. The ParseUrl() is a custom made extension method that corrects it.

Comment: Awesome I will try PreInit event, this should be it right?
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {//code}

Comment: I tried using the PreInit and now it seems that the Linkbuttons is not getting generated. It might be beacuse the PreInit executes before my click event?

Comment: Sure it will execute *before* your event handler. That's the point! You cannot *first* execute an event handler which is wasn't yet initialized.

Comment: You should really read some tutorial about ASP.NET page life-cycle and handling of postbacks.

Comment: Hmm well I store important data in viewstates by the click event handler that I need to use when I create the linkbuttons.